# jquery limit characters

Tags: jquery, character

```
var encoded = $("#bauer").text();
var charLength = encoded.length;
```

I then want to take encoded and put it in a tweet. How can i make sure the charLength doesnt exceed 140 characters for the tweet - ie. it still sends the tweet but trims it below 140 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use javascript's substring method.

```
if(encoded.length > 140){
 encoded = encoded.substring(0, 140);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `encoded.substring(0,140)` for this task (if you really want trimming to occur).

Comment: That will limit it to 139 characters, not 140.

Comment: @T.J.: fixed. That 1 will always mess you up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the question. Because if I do, add:

```
encoded = encoded.substring(0, 140);
```

...after which the `encoded` string will be (at most) 140 characters long. (You don't even need to check `charLength` first, if you don't mind possibly making one unnecessary function call; `substring` doesn't care if the second parameter is out of bounds.)